# Kentico custom page url with URL "Path or Pattern" feature

Tags: kentico

**Updated:** As I put in the comment under Brenden's response. I think the issue is not related to multilingual site, but it's with using Properties/ URLs / Path or Pattern feature. After adding value to the field Path of Pattern, the whole navigation stops working properly.

---

I have a multilingual site (English, French). Currently the URLs are like below:
English: *www.domain.com/en-us/contact-us* 
French: *www.domain.com/fr-fr/contact-us*

What I want for French is a custom (translated) url ***www.domain.com/fr-fr/contactez-nous***

I followed [this Kentico instruction](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/multilingual-websites/setting-up-multilingual-websites/configuring-urls-for-multilingual-websites) - the bottom part of the page with using Path or Pattern by adding /contactez-nous in the box. Things seem ok, but upon clicking on the page with the new URL on the French site, the whole main navigation (done with Hierarchical Viewer) seems to stuck with that URL; clicking anywhere on the nav doesn't do anything.

Links outside the nav works fine. How to make the nav work again. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. The **GetDocumentURL()** is using **NodeAliasPath** to determine the URL. However, if you have not specified the **NodeAliasPath** column in the Columns property of the hierarchical viewer, then the current page's **NodeAliasPath** is used - and thus all items have the same URL. Adding the **NodeAliasPath** to the **Columns** property should fix the issue, so the hierarchical viewer has access to the data of each individual item.

**EDIT**: it looks like that in some cases the **DocumentURLPath** column must be specified too.

Comment: I've checked and do have these in the Columns property: DocumentMenuCaption, DocumentMenuClass, NodeAliasPath

Comment: Could you please try adding also the DocumentURLPath?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're testing this in another browser or even another browser in a private window.  If you are testing in a new tab in the same window, the CMS caches the selected language in the Kentico UI and shows that in the browser window.

For instance, if you have selected "French" on the pages app in the bottom left under the content tree, then navigate to your site in a new tab, it will display French no matter how many times you change the language selector on your public site to a new language.

Secondly, check the URL aliases for the given pages in each language.  Make sure you don't have an alias that is the same in each language.  For instance `/contact-us` with French and `/contact-us` in English.

Comment: I think the issue is not related to multilingual site, but it's with using **Properties/ URLS / Path or Pattern** feature. I have just tried this on the English site: under URLs, add  /contact-us-NEW in the Path or Pattern field. The URL of that page is changed to www.domain.com/en-us/contact-us-NEW. However, upon viewing that page, everything else on the main nav stop working, stop taking you to other pages like it's supposed to. Maybe I missed something very basic. Could you advise?

Comment: Are you forcing the domain cultures in settings?

Comment: Not totally sure what you meant by that, but I looked at Sites > General > Cultures and notice the value for Default content culture and Visitor culture are set to English - United States.

Comment: This is in Settings > URLs & SEO > SEO - Cultures

Comment: Thanks. All 3 check boxes are unchecked

Comment: What transformation are you using to get the value for the link? Is the transformation method getting the right value from the right culture version of the page (CMS_Tree vs CMS_Document tables). It looks like you are getting the value incorrectly from the current item and current culture.

Comment: I used Hierarchical transformation for the nav. The nav works fine for all sites (all languages). It just stops working when I add some value to the Path or Pattern field per the Kentico instructions mentioned above. For the transformation, I have transformation for the first, middle, and last item. Here's how the middle item transformation looks like: {% if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(DocumentMenuClass)) { %}<li>{% } else { %}
<li class="{% HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuClass)%}">{% } #%}<a href="{% GetDocumentUrl()%}">{% HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption)%}</a>
{^SubLevelPlaceHolder^}
</li>